# Button listener not working in Preference fragment

Tags: android

I've created a subclass of `PreferenceFragment` that implements `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener`. I have one preference that contains a `Switch` (a subclass of `CompoundButton`). Here's the callback I've created for when the value of the switch changes:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    mAppController.doSomething(isChecked);
    Log.v("rose_tag", "hi");
}
```

I declare the preference in `OnCreate` as follows:

```
Switch mySwitch = (Switch) myView.findViewById(R.id.switch);
mySwitch.setEnabled(true);
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

The callback gets called when the view first opens (a breakpoint in the callback is hit), but no log prints, and the callback never gets called again, even when I switch the switch on and off. How can I make this callback work?

I also tried creating an inline anonymous listener. I also tried using a simple `Button` with an `onClick` listener, and that didn't work either.

Comment: have You checked Your imports? Sometimes it happens that there is a wrong import declaration. Is Your onCheckedChangeListener imported as follows: android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener ?

Comment: I have `import android.widget.CompoundButton`

Comment: maybe an alternative is to: mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){}); instead of setting on implemented chekedChangeListener. Could You try this?

Comment: Yes, I already tried this. I also tried using a simple `Button` with an `onClick` listener, and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can see you are trying to use [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) as any other normal fragment. However, you must to take in count the correct mechanism, one example is you cannot use all the widgets for making a preferences view for the user, you must use the [Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html) objects (see Preference subclasses).

Another example is that you must use `addPreferencesFromResource(int)` to inflate preferences from an XML resource.

Check both links above and this [example](http://android-er.blogspot.mx/2012/07/example-of-using-preferencefragment.html).

I hope It helps you.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the anwser from Jorge Gil, you will not be able to easily get a reference to the view you are declaring in the PreferenceScreen.
However you can easily get one of the preference Object which in that case is a SwitchPreference. So in your res/xml/preferences.xml add your switch preference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="screen">

    <SwitchPreference
            android:key="switch_preference"
            android:title="title"
            android:summary="summary" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Then in your PreferenceFragment/PreferenceActivity's onCreate function add this:

```
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);      
    SwitchPreference switchPref = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("switch_preference");

    switchPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),"onPreferenceChange:" + newValue);
            return true;
        }
    });
```